# How to improve StereoSGBM results with texture

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So I'm doing stereo 360 for 6Dof for a high school senior project. My disparity results are decent but I was wondering if there's a way to make them better, specifically with how they handle texture. The disparity map should fade away as points get farther away, but, because StereoSGBM isn't handling texture well, far away points are unreasonably close. Also the sky should appear black but it's pretty light.

Disparity map:
[image: Disparity map]

I'm using StereoSGBM to get a disparity map for 2 Ricoh Theta SC cameras. I've tried adjusting the disparity settings and playing with brightness and contrast with the inputted images. I've also tried changing the StereoSGBM mode (HH, SGBM, SGBM_3WAY), flipping the input images, and using StereoBM instead of SGBM. I haven't tried calibrating the cameras (besides shifting the images so the cameras point in the exact same direction) because I figured that if camera calibration were an issue I would get far worse results. Is there some other disparity function I could use besides StereoSGBM that would get me a better result. Should I try using machine learning with Google Cloud to create a better disparity model? I could us NYU Depth Dataset ([https://cs.nyu.edu/~silberman/datasets/nyu_depth_v2.html](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Esilberman/datasets/nyu_depth_v2.html)) to train the model. Does anyone have any ideas for how to improve my results?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageOps


def func_disparity(window_size, minDisparity2, numDisparities2, blockSize2, 
    disp12MaxDiff2, uniquenessRatio2, speckleWindowSize2, speckleRange2, 
    preFilterCap2, brightness,
    contrast, event=None):

    imgR = Image.open(FILE_NAME)
    imgL = Image.open(FILEN_NAME)
    print(imgL.size)

    imgL = ImageOps.expand(imgL, border=50)
    imgR = ImageOps.expand(imgR, border=50)    
    
    contrastL = ImageEnhance.Contrast(imgL)
    contrastR = ImageEnhance.Contrast(imgR)
    imgL = contrastL.enhance(contrast)
    imgR = contrastR.enhance(contrast)

    brightnessL = ImageEnhance.Brightness(imgL)
    brightnessR = ImageEnhance.Brightness(imgR)
    imgL = brightnessL.enhance(brightness)
    imgR = brightnessR.enhance(brightness)

    imgL = imgL.convert('L')
    imgL = np.array(imgL)
    imgR = imgR.convert('L')
    imgR = np.array(imgR)
    
    
    #window_size = 15                     wsize default 3; 5; 7 for SGBM reduced size image; 15 for SGBM full size image (1300px and above); 5 Works nicely
 
    left_matcher = cv.StereoSGBM_create(
        minDisparity=minDisparity2,
        numDisparities=numDisparities2,             # max_disp has to be 
        dividable by 16 f. E. HH 192, 256
        blockSize= blockSize2,
        P1=8 * 3 * window_size ** 2,    # wsize default 3; 5; 7 for SGBM 
        reduced size image; 15 for SGBM full size image (1300px and above); 5 
        Works nicely
        P2=32 * 3 * window_size ** 2,
        disp12MaxDiff=disp12MaxDiff2,
        uniquenessRatio=uniquenessRatio2,
        speckleWindowSize=speckleWindowSize2,
        speckleRange=speckleRange2,
        preFilterCap= preFilterCap2,
        mode=cv.STEREO_SGBM_MODE_SGBM_3WAY
        )

    right_matcher = cv.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(left_matcher)

    # FILTER Parameters
    lmbda = 80000
    sigma = 1.2
    visual_multiplier = 1.0
 
    wls_filter = 
    cv.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(matcher_left=left_matcher)
    wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
    wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)

    print('computing disparity...')
    displ = left_matcher.compute(imgL, imgR)  # .astype(np.float32)/16
    dispr = right_matcher.compute(imgR, imgL)  # .astype(np.float32)/16
    displ = np.int16(displ)
    dispr = np.int16(dispr)
    filteredImg = wls_filter.filter(displ, imgL, None, dispr)  # important to 
    put "imgL" here!!!

    filteredImg = cv.normalize(src=filteredImg, dst=filteredImg, beta=0, 
    alpha=255, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX);
    filteredImg = np.uint8(filteredImg)

    height, width = filteredImg.shape
    filteredImg = np.delete(filteredImg, np.s_[0:50], axis=0)
    filteredImg = np.delete(filteredImg, np.s_[height-100:height-50], axis=0)
    filteredImg = np.delete(filteredImg, np.s_[0:50], axis=1)
    filteredImg = np.delete(filteredImg, np.s_[width-100:width-50], axis=1)
    print(filteredImg.shape)
    
    return(filteredImg)
    #print(filteredImg)
    #file = Image.fromarray(filteredImg)
    #file.save("disparitymap.jpg")
    print("Done")

window_size = 3
minDisparity2 = 15
numDisparities2=16      #160max_disp has to be dividable by 16 f. E. HH 192, 
blockSize2=20   #Maybe 20 is optimal
disp12MaxDiff2=1
uniquenessRatio2=15
speckleWindowSize2=0
speckleRange2=2
preFilterCap2=63
brightness=1
contrast=1

disparity = func_disparity(window_size, minDisparity2, numDisparities2, blockSize2, disp12MaxDiff2, uniquenessRatio2, speckleWindowSize2, speckleRange2, preFilterCap2, brightness, contrast, event=None)

file = Image.fromarray(disparity)
file.show()
```

Comment: Interesting project.  I have to admit was largely unaware of this field. For anyone else interested, I found [this](http://nefeli.lib.teicrete.gr/browse/stef/epp/2015/ChoustoulakisEmmanouil/attached-document-1446199791-653661-11173/ChoustoulakisEmmanouil2015.pdf) , a nice reference to stereo vision &  disparity mapping. Best practice is to describe all abbreviations when first used: i.e. Semi Global Block Matching  (SGBM). Good luck on your project. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @zipit Thanks! I'm trying one of the functions from that research paper right now

Comment: @zipzit Thanks for you help, unfortunately the functions that were best rated in the research paper produced results that were considerable worse than the semi global block matching algorithm

Comment: @ekol any luck on this subject at the end? what was your final outcome? could you share the code please? :)